# How to save an image using its URL in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a problem to save an image with its URL. I once used URLWRITE function. it works well for most of image urls. However, for this one: http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/157/1562-cute-little-cat.jpg , I cannot save this image to my disk using `urlwrite(url, 'cat.jpg');` . Anyone can help ? Thanks !

PS. the saved image cannot be opened.
After I click the url, the image is as this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem will be with that sites and the url forwarding due MVC i guess. If you click at your link, you dont get the exact image. You get the sites where you need to click at the download button and wait 10 or how much seconds. Probably if you get the IMAGE link.. you will have no problems. But you dont in here. Its not problem of your script or in urlwrite function it is "problem" (probably intention) of that sites

Comment: The link I provided is the image url.

Comment: Its not for me. If i click at that link i get that url sites where is just a thumbnail of the image..

Comment: This is the webpage after I click the url. i have added it to the question. Also I right clicked the image on the webpage and checked its image location. It is exactly what I provided.

Comment: Yes..but if that sites are model-view-controller, they can forward you to some "index" page. And that image source will be right. But because of controller catch all requests, and because of controller doesnt know that page, it forward you to that "download" page where throught parameter will display that image in that <a></a> component. Otherwise if you dont think this is solution i have no another answer :]..i send you printscreen how it looks by me..

Comment: So if i click at your image, i am forward and it shows me this:
http://i.imgur.com/E3gk82r.jpg
i tried that at 3 different devices at 3 different explorers..

Comment: do you know what?? I see now how did you get that image you are posting..If you click on the download button..it is counting 15sec to download and after that it shows you save-open dialbox..if you close it or if your browser doesnt redirect, you can click at CLICK HERE button and it shows you the image you posted..but its how i said thourht MVC..and that link is generated by javascript..So in this case you are not able to get image like that..simply with urlwrite you can get only direct links..but this is not direct link and it is probably post-generated

Comment: en, I see. But how can I use urlwrite to download it ? the picture must be saved on the Internet and we have the url to that image. Then why can we not download it ?

Comment: i am not sure. It would be saved in blob in database and you have no chance to get it..and how it seems, it is so..because if you put a direct link, it shows that page i sended..so i think at this sites and on similar sites where you have a "waiting" and after that link generating, you are not possible to get it over matlab..